# How to minimize delay time between splash screen and home screen in roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on Roku app using Scene Graph component. I want to remove delay(which occurs with fading) between splash screen and home screen. Means after splash screen I want to show home screen wihout fading animation.

Please help...

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've made an entry in the Manifest file of "splash_min_time=0" also do an entry of "splash_rsg_optimization=1". This is available on/after Roku OS v7.6. Removes Flicker/Fading as well.

Comment: Thanks :) Set this attribute to remove the black screen flash in SceneGraph channels. This is only applicable for SceneGraph channels and only if the first screen is a SceneGraph component

Answer (score 1):

How long is that delay you are unhappy about?

Have you tried [manifesting](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Manifest+File#ManifestFile-SplashScreenAttributes) `splash_min_time=0`?
You might be surprised but the default is 1600 (ms)...